# Run process on specific monitor

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program that, among other things, launches processes (i use winapi function CreateProcess for it)

Problems start when the system has more than one monitor.
I need the ability to specify which monitor to display the process windows.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you populating the STARUPINFO structure with for the dwX, dwY, dwXSize, dwYSize?

Comment: Typo:  STARTUPINFO structure.  MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Eljay nothing, i call CreateProcess, than (if necessary) SetWindowPos

Comment: @Eljay This isn't a general solution, because: _"For GUI processes, the specified position is used the first time the new process calls CreateWindow to create an **overlapped** window if the x parameter of CreateWindow is **CW_USEDEFAULT**."_ (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ShellExecuteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx), which takes a [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. It has an `hMonitor` member to specify a monitor by handle.

To get the handle of a monitor, call [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx), which enumerates all available display monitors and triggers a [`MonitorEnumProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145061(v=vs.85).aspx) callback function for each one. Implement the callback function and gather the `hMonitor` handle for the desired monitor.  Use that in the `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` structure when calling `ShellExecuteEx()`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `CreateProcess()` does have an *undocumented* feature that lets you specify an `HMONITOR` handle in the `STARTUPINFO` struct (`ShellExecuteEx()` makes use of this feature internally):

[Undocumented CreateProcess](https://is.muni.cz/el/1433/jaro2010/PB167/um/cv5/undocumented_CreateProcess.pdf)

> ### Specify which monitor a process should start on
>
> The next undocumented tip uses another unknown STARTUPINFO flag. This flag has the value 0x400, and I have given it the name STARTF_MONITOR.
>
> When this flag is specified in the dwFlags member, the STARTUPINFO's hStdOutput member is used to specify a handle to a monitor, on which to start the new process. This monitor handle can be obtained by any of the multiple-monitor display functions (i.e. EnumDisplayMonitors, MonitorFromPoint, MonitorFromWindow etc).
>
> ```
> BOOL CALLBACK EnumMonitorProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdc, LPRECT rect, LPARAM data)
> {
>   STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
>   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
>   char szExe[] = "sol.exe";
>
>   // specify which monitor to use
>   si.dwFlags = STARTF_MONITOR;
>   si.hStdOutput = hMonitor;
>
>   // start solitaire on specified monitor
>   if(CreateProcess(0, szExe, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
>   {
>       CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
>       CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
>   }
> }
>
> // call EnumMonitorProc (above) for every installed monitor on the system
> void Demo()
> {
>   EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, EnumMonitorProc, 0);
> }
> ```
>
> The example above uses the EnumDisplayMonitors API call as a method of obtaining a monitor handle (one for each monitor installed). The EnumMonitorProc function simply starts a new instance of Solitaire on each monitor in turn.
>
> There are certain restrictions which should be noted here. You may be asking yourself why the above example works, when you know full well that the
> hStdOutput member should be used for a standard-output pipe. The answer to this question is simple - when the undocumented STARTF_MONITOR flag is
> specified, the STARTF_USESTDHANDLES flag is ignored. This means that these two flags cannot be used together, and the hStdInput, hStdOutput and hStdError handles act differently to how they are described in the documentation.
>
> The next restriction is kind of obvious too: when you start a new process with CreateProcess, it has no concept of monitors, windows, or any other GUI related entities. A windows program actually has to physically create it's windows in order to display it's GUI. This is where the restriction for the STARTF_MONITOR flag comes into play. When a process calls CreateWindow, it can specify exactly where the window will appear by using the x, y, width and height parameters. This means that it is not possible for one program to specify where a second program's windows should appear unless this second program creates it's windows in a certain way.
>
> ```
> hWnd = CreateWindow("ClassName",
>                     "Title Text",
>                     WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
>                     CW_USEDEFAULT, // X coordinate
>                     CW_USEDEFAULT, // Y coordinate
>                     width, // Width
>                     height, // Height
>                     0, 0, 0, 0);
>
> ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
> ```
>
> It is only when a program creates a window using the CW_USEDEFAULT values for the coordinates, does the monitor specified by CreateProcess get used. The CreateWindow API call must obviously look inside the current process's STARTUPINFO structure to see what monitor it should create the window on. The Solitaire card-game was used in the example because it creates it's main window in this manner. I couldn't use Notepad as a demonstration because it didn't work - notepad seems to use actual coordinates to display it's main window rather than the CW_USEDEFAULT values.
>
> Note that the ShellExecuteEx API call makes use of this CreateProcess feature in order to implement it's own monitor settings.