# run aplication on second display directly with c winapi

Tags: c, windows, winapi

How can I run an application directly on a specific monitor? For instance, I want to open Google Chrome on my second monitor. I've tried using the CreateProcess function and setting various flags, but it didn't work as expected. I'm wondering if changing the primary monitor to the second one could be a potential solution?
i've tested with createprocess set to x,y, and with hStdOutput hmonitor
tested with ShellExecuteEx()
[Run process on specific monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588012/run-process-on-specific-monitor)
[How to programmatically start an application on a specific monitor on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822908/how-to-programmatically-start-an-application-on-a-specific-monitor-on-windows-10)
all tested
tested with run chrome in sw_hide, but chrome not running in sw_hide
and how to get handle to main window?

Comment: Have you tried SetWindowPos() ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos

Comment: but how will u get hwnd of chrome runned for example ?

Comment: dont close this questions, this problem not solved

Comment: If you want to re-open the question, you need to edit it to add more details and explain why these will not work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822908/how-to-programmatically-start-an-application-on-a-specific-monitor-on-windows-10  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588012/run-process-on-specific-monitor .  Also, read How to Ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i've tested all of this variants, and they not working

Comment: You don't explain in the question why each solution does not work the way you want it to, or how you want it to work.  Just "it doesn't work" is not a good description.  See - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's very not clear from your text, but is your goal to launch an app and then hide its main window?  You can try to do that in 3 steps:  launch, find window, hide window.  Or launch minimized?